# Laravel 5.5 model binding API doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with model binding in Laravel 5.5.

I have in my api.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'tasks'], function() {
    Route::get('delete/{task}', 'TaskController@delete');

});
```

In my Controller:

```
public function delete(Request $request, Task $task){
        var_dump($task->id);

    }
```

In my RouteServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('task', 'App\Models\Task');
}
```

In my App\Http\Kernel

```
'api' => [
                'throttle:60,1',
                'bindings',
            ],
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
            'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
            'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
            'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

        ];
```

But **model Binding doesn't work, my var dump return null**.

If I try to remove Model Binding in controller and use:

```
public function delete(Request $request, $id){
            var_dump(Task::find($id)->id);

        }
```

It works.
what could be the problem?

Comment: This should not break route model binding, but in your controller you use implicit binding by injecting the model instance with `Task $task`. You don't need to register the explicit binding in your RouteServiceProvider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check: `mapApiRoutes` method in `routeServiceProvider.php` and if don't have `->middleware('api')`, add to your method.

You should add `api` middleware or `api` prefix to your API routes.

Reference: [laravel source code](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/29440e8cce7a4f24ecf03f3f894ee4aa627be4bd/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L66)

Comment: Yes, In the upgraded from 5.1 to 5.5 I missed ->middleware('api')  in mapApiRoutes in routeServiceProvider, thanks.

Comment: You don't need to add `api` middleware, all routes in `api.php` are behind this middleware by default.

Comment: Add in your answer to check in : mapApiRoutes in routeServiceProvider and if you don't have, to add ->middleware('api')

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything about having a keyName method on your tasks model.

If you don't have it, that's probably the issue.

Add this to your Task model to override the default method:

```php
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'id';
}
```

Edit: I just tested this and it defaults to ID. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Thankyou but it'not make sense, because the ID is already the default

Comment: The standard for the routeKeyName is the primary key: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1466

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the bindings (or api) middleware to your routes :

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'tasks'], function() {
    Route::get('delete/{task}', 'TaskController@delete');
})->middleware('bindings');
```

Comment: Yes! if i put the middleware in the route it works. But Why? with 'api: [ 'binding']' it'is shouldn't be explicit?

Comment: Can be a cache problem, use `php artisan cache:clear`. Did you upgrade from older version of Laravel ? and if you use `api` middleware, is it working ?

Comment: Yes I have upgraded from older, but actually I have installed new version and all my code in the new project, so I should have all config.

Comment: Yes, In the upgraded I missed ->middleware('api')  in mapApiRoutes in routeServiceProvider, thanks

Comment: When you adding `api` middleware to your routes it automatically use `binding` middleware. I think @immeyti answer is right.

Comment: @mharbiee , yes, I saw in the second moment the answer.

Comment: The answer is absolutely the same I wrote 20 minutes before (adding `api` to your api routes). Which is not the correct answer, I asked you to try to verify if you had a routes problem or other. Since I asked you if you upgraded your Laravel. Please remove the downvote to keep some logic here.

Comment: Yes, I Upvoted your answer, I don't know Who have downvoted. Please update Your answer with "if you upgrade check in your routeService PRovider ecc" And I will accept your answer instead of  immeyti, Thankyou !